# What is Chronic immobilization stress (CIS)?

Tags: terminology

I am trying to self study BNDF a little bit when I found this article:

> Abstract Stress impacts multiple systems within the CNS, including the
>   hippocampus. A key molecular mediator in hippocampal functions,
>   including learning and memory, is brain-derived neurotrophic factor
>   (BDNF). BDNF mRNA is reported to be decreased following chronic (every
>   day) immobilization stress (CIS) in the rat, however the effect on
>   protein is unknown. Utilizing a mouse model of CIS, the hypothesis
>   that total hippocampal BDNF protein, in addition to BDNF mRNA, would
>   be decreased was tested. The effects of intermittent (alternating day)
>   immobilization and cold stress on hippocampal BDNF protein levels was
>   also examined.
>
> In this study it was demonstrated that CIS results in a small (8 per
>   cent decrease relative to non-stressed controls), but significant (p =
>   0.0013) decrease in the exon coding for mature BDNF (exon VI). In addition, there was a significant (34 per cent, p = 0.005) decrease in
>   the mRNA coding for exon I in the stressed animals. Contrary to
>   expectations, however, CIS resulted in a significant (116 per cent, p
>   = 0.0087) increase in hippocampal BDNF protein levels. Furthermore, both intermittent immobilization and chronic cold stress both
>   increased BDNF protein levels. Chronic stress, therefore,
>   differentially regulates BDNF mRNA and protein levels in the
>   hippocampus. Copyright © 2004 John Wiley & Sons, Ltd.

I'm really curious what they mean with CIS: Chronic immobilization stress.
I can't find anything on the internet that actually explains what this is.

Answer (score 1):

There are >1200 articles tagged "[chronic immobilization stress](http://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=chronic%20immobilization%20stress)" on pubmed.

From Hennebelle et al. (2012):

> Half of the 6-month old male rats from each dietary group were subjected to a validated chronic stress procedure (Buyntsky and Mostosky, 2009) based on a restraint stress procedure adapted from Veena et al, [32]. Rats were placed in wire mesh restrainers for 6 h a day (fom 10 am to 16 pm) for 21 days (5 days a week) over a period of 4 weeks. Unstressed rats were handled weekly. The unstressed and stressed animals were housed in different rooms.

[Hennebelle, H., et al. 2012. Influence of Omega-3 Fatty Acid Status on the Way Rats Adapt to Chronic Restraint Stress. PLoSOne 7: e42142.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3408452/)

Comment: So Chronic Immmobilization Stress means they don't allow (the rats in most cases) to move freely ?

Comment: Yes for certain period of time.